# How to make the drawer in the scaffold at the top of the screen and the BottomNavigationBar is behind on the drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, drawer, scaffold

[Please see this pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hszLR.png)
This picture is what happening in my code.

I want the drawer to be on top of the bottomnavigationbar. I want the bottomnavigationbar behind the drawer.

Comment: Keep these guidelines to post questions on Stack Overflow for better visibility for the readers stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

hey for do that you need to work with bottomSheet :

```
  bottomSheet:Container(child: .....,)
```

Comment: but still the bottomsheet is above the drawer.

Comment: when the drawer is open, i want it to be on the on the very front. That means the bottomsheet or bottomnavigationbar is behind of the drawer.